# Mysql Command to do parsing

Tags: mysql

I have a table that was migrated from a older system.  The table contains some values that is no longer valid.  I need to be able to change the invalid data to valid data.  The table only has 2 columns - id and who, both are int values.

The id column is the job id of stored jobs.
The who id is the people assigned to the job.
I have a who id = 10 is not invalid in the new system.  So I need to change every instance of 10 to 16.

```
Table CC

id    |   who

mysql> select * from cc;

1     |   2

1     |   3

2      |  1

2     |  10

mysql> select * from CC where id = 2;

2     | 1

2  | 10

mysql> select * from CC where who = 10;

2  |  10
```

Is there a way to do the above command and change the value at the same time?

```
mysql> update CC set who = '16' where who = 10;
```

Will this work?

Comment: try it and it will work, in this case, single quote is optional since the data type is integer. http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f4d4c/1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
update CC set who = 16 where who = 10;
```

I removed the quotes around the 16 becuase that is an int.

Comment: even if you didn't remove, it will still work. there is nothing wrong with the query the OP gave. it just that he didn't tried to execute it.